# Performance question: js querySelectorAll VS css :has pseudo

Tags: javascript, css, gsap

I want to animate a custom cursor by hovering buttons.
The tutorial I followed is here: https://tympanus.net/codrops/2019/01/31/custom-cursor-effects/
It's using requestAnimationFrame and TweenMax to move the custom cursor in the right direction.
I just wondering, is there any performance difference if I use:

- javascript querySelectorAll and addEventListener("mouseenter"), then "mouseleave" in a for loop for the buttons, and using TweenMax to animate the cursor by then, as it was in the demo,
- or is it could better with pure CSS html:has(button:hover) .cursor{} version in 2023?

Comment: Can you afford to have this not working for Firefox users in 2023? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has#browser_compatibility